# textarea value not getting using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am not getting the value present in `textarea` instead of that I am getting empty value.

```
textarea id="arid_WIN_3_1000000218" class="text sr " wrap="off" rows="1" arautoctt="400" arautocak="0" arautocmb="1" arautoc="1" mstyle="2" armenu="CTM:SGL:Assignee-HPD-Q" style="top:0px; left:117px; width:174px; height:21px;" maxlen="69" cols="20" title="Nilendu Kumar"></textarea>
```

and my Java code is

```
String textBoxValue=driver.findElement(By.id("arid_WIN_1_1000000218")).getAttribute("value");
```

Please let me know if am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of a `<textarea>` isn't in the value *attribute*, it's in the value *property* in a DOM object. With Selenium, you need to use `getText()`, so try:

```
String textBoxValue=driver.findElement(By.id("arid_WIN_1_1000000218")).getText();
```

Comment: `driver.findElement` returns a `WebElement` and `WebElement` does not have a field called `value`. Your assumption and your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @LINGS Yep, fixed it.

Comment: There is a possibility of the id being generated dynamically and hence, hardcoding arid_WIN_3_1000000218 may not be able to find the text-area element. Try using driver.findElement(By.Class("text sr ")).getAttribute("value") or add a data-test-id="some_constant_value" to your element and use driver.findElement(By.xpath(//text-area['data-test-id="some_constant_value"']).getAttribute('value')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my example will help :

```
driver.findElement(By.className("rich_text_editor")).getAttribute("**titel**");
```